# Display all columns in in ruby left joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using rails 2 active record and I am trying to perform a left join on two tables. I have in issue in seeing the all columns names the tables. I only see the columns of one table

```
Students.all(:joins => "LEFT JOIN user on students.id =  cards.id")
```

The Sql generated by Active Records is:

```
SELECT `students`.* FROM `students`  LEFT JOIN cards on students.email = cards.id
```

One can notice here the the `SELECT` statement is only on `students` table.
How can I fetch the columns from the `cards` table as well?

I am using ruby 1.8 and Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1):

By default, Model.find selects all the fields from the result set using select *.

You can specify the subset via :select option on the find.

Please use this instead

```
Students.all(:select => "students.*, user.*", :joins => "LEFT JOIN user on students.id =  cards.id")
```

[Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html)